# Where do I find the code for the open-source game Warmux?

Tags: android

I found an open source game called Warmux but I don't know how to get the code.  I downloaded the file from [here](http://www.wormux.org/phpboost/download/download-14+warmux-11-04-1-for-android.php), but I don't know where to go from there.  I didn't find any instructions on how to use the source.
While I was looking for it, I came across something called git and repo. Do I use that?

Comment: The apk and datafiles are binaries, not source code. So they wont help much. Git is a source repository system. It's a program they use to store all the source-code and to store all changes. You need to install Git and pull the source code from their servers. This can be a bit cumbersome since GIT isn't the easiest to use especially if you haven't heard of source control systems before. Try looking up a good tutorial :).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The source code is available as a compressed file [here](http://www.wormux.org/phpboost/download/download-13+warmux-11-04-1-source-code.php). You'll have to use an unzip tool to extract the files, something like [7zip](http://www.7-zip.org/) would work, since I assume you're on a Windows machine.

Keep in mind it looks like this code and its associated files were created on linux, so some of the files won't have extensions and it'll probably be somewhat confusing if you haven't see that before. Good luck.

Check out the `src` folder, it's where you'll find all the code.

Comment: Thanks i've done that already but I noticed that the files inside the src folder are CPP and H files.  Wouldn't i need java files to see the source code?  I only ask this because I've been using Eclipse in programming.

Comment: Java is just one programming language. There are many. Files ending with .cpp are typically C++ files.

Comment: Can I still use the code for C++ in Java, with a couple changes? Or is it completely different, I don't want to waste my time trying to change the code to java if it would be very difficult and tedious.

Comment: As far as you're concerned, they are completely different. They'll share underlying patterns and structure, but you won't be able to easily convert from one to the other.

Comment: Voting up because I think this effectively answers the question asked.  However getting into differences between C++ and Java, and what GIT is is another question (not appropriate for this list) altogether.

Comment: @BluFire Remember to accept answers that helped you. Even if it turned out to be bad news in the end :)